# openshift DB config causing 503

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I seem to be getting a 503 with any attempts to access my DB. I am using env variables as per documentation:

```
define('DB_SERVER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')); 
define('DB_USER',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASSWORD',getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME',getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

$link = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

if ($link->connect_errno) {

die('Connect Error (' . $link->connect_errno . ') '
    . $link->connect_error);
}
mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
```

The only result I get is a 503 there is nothing in the logs to indicate any issues but then again I'm not sure if I need to do any config of the logs on openshift to expose that. I'm new to this service.

update: The cause of the 503 is ambiguous. At the moment I get it if my index is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('lib/resources/config.php'); ?>
```

and my config.php starts with:

```
<?php die('test');
```

I'm killing it right at the top of the include file so it's not my code, something else must be crashing, how do I figure it out?

Comment: Are you getting 503 or 530 (login incorrect)? I think that posting here the exact error message may help people answering you.

Answer (score 0):

So after more research I determined the issue. With open shift if you use:

```
rhc tail appname
```

It gives you the errors actually causing the issues. In my case it was a syntax error further down the code.